# RedeclareSectionCommand, beforeskip not working

Tags: spacing, sectioning, koma-script

I am trying to have sections have space before them using `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.  `beforeskip` will work for this, but I also want the section to start on a new page and when I put it onto a new page, the `beforeskip` disappears. Does anyone know a way around this?

I am using KOMA version 3.25.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=2in,afterskip=0pt]{section}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use sections and not `\chapter{Wombat}`?

Comment: Do you want *all* sections to start on a new page like chapters do? In this case you can use `style=chapter` to change the heading style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want *all* sections to start a new page, you can change the style of sections from `section` to `chapter`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2018/12/30]% new KOMA-Script release needed
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for some dummy text
\begin{document}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,beforeskip=2in,afterskip=0pt,afterindent=false]{section}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Please note, this suggestion needs at least KOMA-Script 3.26, because of option `afterindent=false`. With an old KOMA-Script you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for some dummy text
\begin{document}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter,beforeskip=-2in,afterskip=0pt]{section}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

to get the same result:

[image: two section pages]

The second code example uses a negative `beforeskip` value to avoid the indent of the first paragraph after the heading. I do like the solution with an explicit `afterindent=false` more.

Answer (score -1):

I have now solved the issue by adding `\vspace*{0pt}` before `section`.